# Increasing Covalent character increases Colour intensity

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, color, periodic-trends, covalent-compounds

I observed some trends as follows:-

- $\ce{PbCl2}$ white and $\ce{PbI2}$ yellow
- $\ce{SnCl2}$ white, $\ce{SnCl4}$ red and $\ce{SnI4}$ black
- $\ce{AgCl}$ white, $\ce{AgI}$, $\ce{AgBr}$ and $\ce{Ag2CO3}$ yellow

In all these cases as the size of anion increases ( polarisability increases)  or charge on cation increases (polarising power increases) colour exhibited becomes darker.. How does increasing covalent character affect this?  Or is there  any other reason?

Comment: In silver compounds colour is mostly due to charge transfer.

Comment: tin(IV) chloride is a colorless liquid and tin(IV) iodide is orange solid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In molecular orbital theory, as the covalent character increases the homo-lumo gap decreases, and the excitation happens more easily. Thus the colour intensity increases.